# No emails are sent to the added and granted user, nor does the user see any locks via the tapkey app while the grants for looks are set

Tags: tapkey

I tried to add a user using the Web API via client credentials and via identity provider. Neither resulted in the invited user receiving an email or seeing the granted lock in his app.

1. I called /api/v1/Owners to get the owner account's ID for the locks I want a new user to grant access for.
2. I created a new contact by posting to /api/v1/Owners//Contacts only setting email as identifier (not posting any other data) and using the ownerAccountId from step 1
3. With the newly created contact id from step 2, ownerAccountId from step 1 and boundlock id  I did a put request to /api/v1/Owners//Grants
4. This resulted in a 200 response, but the new contact did not get any notify or invite email.
5. When I login to my.portal.nl as owner of the lock I do see the the added user as smartphone user with correct lock and validFrom and validBefore

I expect the invited user in step 4 to be emailed. What am I missing? In your comment you say :  Generally speaking, Tapkey will usually not send emails to users.
But how do new users get notified about new locks the can open?

Via the API I do see the users and grants are actually added. I have checked spam folders, but no emails.

When I register as one of these user by using the emailadress I setup as identity and login into the tapkey app, still no locks.

The client ID I'm using is c2f11e47604639323320d08f8e4038f4 and the owner account id is e12e4145-3afb-45ae-81f5-2cdd57d89fb5

Comment: Hi, can you give us some more context about your scenario? The referenced docs relate to the Tapkey Mobile SDK _for Embedded Devices_. Are we talking about embedded? In that case there are no users having email addresses, so I guess we're not talking about embedded.

Generally speaking, Tapkey will usually not send emails to users. You may want to check the following Getting Started Video related to creating Grants via Client Credentials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IPg9VV1CW4

Comment: Hi i've edited my question. I have watched the linked video, but this not answer the questions I have.

Comment: Well, basically this looks all good. Actually the user will *not* be emailed. However, the user can sign into the Tapkey App, where the permission should be visible. Make sure, that the user logs in using the same email address as the one you specified as identifier. When the user opens the menu within the Tapkey App, their email address will be displayed at the bottom left. Check, whether it matches!

Answer (score 0):

I will just summarize what was already explained by Markus in his answer:

*Regarding the question about the email:*

User will *not* be informed by email if you create a grant for him.

*Regarding the permissions:*

If you have created permissions for an user with an identity provider *tapkey* then these grants are visible for the user once he logs in into the Tapkey app and navigates to his smartphone keys.

If you have created permissions for an user with your *own identity provider*, these are not displayed in the Tapkey app for a granted user and you need to implement your own application to handle these keys.

We had a look on the grants you have created and as you correctly said, they were created successfuly. All, but one, have been created with your own identity provider and therefore they are not visible in Tapkey app for the granted user. Due to the privacy reasons, I don't want to share anymore details regarding your data here.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Could you please answer this last question: How do new users get notified about new locks they can open (since tapkey generally does send emails to users)?

Comment: Generally, if the grant has been created by a third party application, the application needs to take care of informing the users. Tapkey sends email only when the grant has been created by Tapkey application directly.

Comment: Ok I will make sure we send the invite email ourselves. The most important instruction this message should be that a new user needs to use register at tapkey with the emailaddress I created it's user account with, right? After the user registers, tapkey sends a verfication email with a confirmation link. Is there any way for us to send this verification ourselves as well and retrieve the confirm link from the API somewhere?